# GQL query with multiple condition on one List field

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I want to get object, which listfield contains 'foo', 'bar' and 'foobar' strings. Can I do query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE listfield = 'foo' AND listfield = 'bar' AND listfiled = 'foobar'
```

where listfield = StringListProperty() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note, make sure that your index.yaml file contains all the index permutations you require.  Your query as above would have an index like this:

- kind: Entity
  properties:

  - name: xyz
  - name: listfield
  - name: listfield
  - name: listfield

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that.